# nginx rewrite with the value of the query string only

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from

```
   www.setup.com/view.php?id=213
```

to

```
 www.setup.com/213
```

this is my nginx redirect

```
  location ^~ view.php  {
    if ($query_string ~ "^id=([0-9-]+)$"){
    rewrite ^/view.php$ http://$server_name/%1? break;
    }
  }
```

For some reason it appends

```
  ?id= to the url
```

so it becomes

```
www.setup.com?id=213
```

how can I remove

```
   ?id= from the url?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/view.php$ /$arg_id? redirect; 
}
```